# C# change numbers to small indexes in string

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, subscript

I have string "H20" (chemical formula for water). I would like to change it so that all the numbers in the string would be small (the number 2 would be small index next to the letter H). How can I do that?

Comment: What kind of application are you working on - ASP.NET, WinForms, WPF, Silverlight, Windows Phone, XBox 360, Zune, Windows 8 Metro style, ...? Where/how are you displaying those strings? C# is a programming language. Not presentation which is what you are trying to achieve here, so your question is not properly tagged.

Comment: It's a desktop application just to fetch data. It doesn't matter how I'm displaying data there. Then I send those data to PHP server and then to android phone where it does matter.

Comment: By desktop application you mean WinForms or WPF? And of course that it matters how you are displaying the data. That's your problem right now: properly displaying data.

Comment: WinForm. So it's just matter of displaying then? How would I display them in WinForm than?

Comment: using rtf, html or any other control?

Comment: "How to display subscript text in winforms?" is a valid question, so I don't think this should be closed.

Comment: Even the broader question is valid. There is no compelling reason why the Unicode subscript range should not be used. Pasting the string `H₂O` will work in any Unicode-aware application, irrespective of its formatting technology (HTML, RTF, PDF, XPS, etc).

Comment: @Douglas, then assign "H₂O" to textBox.Text or richTextBox.Text and see the result.

Comment: Just tested it in a WPF TextBox. Renders as expected.

Comment: @Douglas, It is a winform app. see the tag

Comment: Also tested to work in WinForms TextBox. Rendering is not so pretty (albeit correct) in Microsoft Sans Serif, but the font can trivially be changed. Did you test it and get unexpected results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you have the means of displaying the subscript unicode characters, you could easily write your own extension method for subscripting:

```
public static string Subscript(this string normal)
{
    if(normal == null) return normal;

    var res = new StringBuilder();
    foreach(var c in normal)
    {
        char c1 = c;

        // I'm not quite sure if char.IsDigit(c) returns true for, for example, '³',
        // so I'm using the safe approach here
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
        {
            // 0x208x is the unicode offset of the subscripted number characters
            c1 = (char)(c - '0' + 0x2080);
        }
        res.Append(c1);
    }

    return res.ToString();
}
```

Comment: `IsDigit` returns `true` not only for 0-9, but also for many other digits, so your cautionary approach is necessary here. This includes full width digits, and digits from other cultures.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: I already thought so. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: '³' isn't going to match `(c >= '0' && c <= '9')` either. IsDigit might do even better.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: I explicitly _don't_ want to have `'³'` in the results. If there are explicit non-ascii digits, I want to take them as intended and leave them as they are.

Comment: You could also just use a regular expression replace which would be much less code.

Comment: @Joey: Regular expressions may be the "easier" solution, but easier is not always better. And I always try to take the better (if not best) solution, considering development time, impact on performance and maintainability. And in this case the regular expression won't save enough development time to make up for the worse performance.

Comment: I doubt a `Regex.Replace(s, "[0-9]", m=>...)` has noticeably worse performance.

Answer (score 4):

As has been pointed out in the comments, you should typically use some presentation technology for this kind of formatting. For example, in HTML, you could display your text through:

```
<span>H<sub>2</sub>O</span>
```

However, Unicode allocates a [superscripts and subscripts block](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts#Superscripts_and_subscripts_block) for hexadecimal characters which you can take advantage of. Since Unicode is supported natively in .NET, including within string literals, you can use your desired character directly:

```
text = text.Replace("H2O", "H₂O");
```

**Note**: Using the Unicode subscript character would guarantee that your `H₂O` string would render correctly in any Unicode-aware application, irrespective of its formatting technology (HTML, RTF, PDF, XPS, etc).

Below is a screenshot showing how the string renders in a `TextBox` under Windows Forms. To improve legibility, font has been changed to Cambria, 11.25pt.

[image: H₂O as rendered in a TextBox under Windows Forms]

**Edit**: If you want to convert all numerals (not just `2` into `₂`), you could use @Tobias’s code. Here is a regex adaptation of it. I’ve included a lookbehind since I assume that all numerals to be subscripted must be preceded by a letter.

```
text = Regex.Replace(text, @"(?<=[A-Za-z])\d", 
    match => ((char)(match.Value[0] - '0' + '₀')).ToString());
```

The above would transform a string like

```
CF3CH2Cl + Br2 → CF3CHBrCl + HBr
```

into

```
CF₃CH₂Cl + Br₂ → CF₃CHBrCl + HBr
```